# GnuTLS / Apache not sending Certificate Chain

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, gnutls

Firslty I'm new to GnuTLS and I have two problems with my Apache / GnuTLS configuration. I was looking for an answear through google but found nothing what could resolve my problems.

The first this one should be easy, I hope :). When I test my configuration 
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.moj-samochod.pl&hideResults=on I recive sometimes B Grade or F Grade ( do not know why sometimes I'm open for POODLE (TLS) attack and sometimes not ) my GnuTSL Priority string is looking that way:

GnuTLSPriorities NORMAL:-VERS-SSL3.0:+VERS-TLS1.0:+VERS-TLS1.2:+VERS-DTLS1.0:+AEAD:+SHA256:!MD5:!ARCFOUR-128:!ARCFOUR-40:+3DES-CBC:+CAMELLIA-256-CBC:+AES-256-CBC:+AES-128-CBC:+ECDHE-RSA:!DHE-RSA:!DHE-DSS:+CURVE-ALL:+CURVE-SECP521R1:%COMPAT:%VERIFY_ALLOW_X509_V1_CA_CRT:%SERVER_PRECEDENCE

The second problem is I think a little bit more complicated. My Certificate Chain is some how broken but only on the webbrowser. When I use certtool -e infile I recive this output

Loaded 3 certificates, 1 CAs and 0 CRLs

```
Subject: C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
Issuer: C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,OU=Root CA,CN=GlobalSign Root CA
Checked against: C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,OU=Root CA,CN=GlobalSign Root CA
Output: Verified.

Subject: C=PL,OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=www.moj-samochod.pl
Issuer: C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
Checked against: C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
Output: Verified.
```

Chain verification output: Verified.

But when I try with webbrowser or any other tool to access the site I recive information that the chain is brokem.

With cUrl or openssl when I'm trying to access the site. First I recieve a problem with the certificate but when I access the site with the appended CA root certificate everything works fine :/

SNI works fine, mod_ssl is erased from the config file.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: This looks like a configuration problem on the web server, so that the server does not send the full chain. SSLLabs complains about incomplete chain too. Since server configuration regarding the certificates is unknown one cannot help here. SSL ciphers are unrelated to this and thus don't help.

Comment: I figured it out since my server is a little bit old CentOS5 ( gona replace it soon ), I needed at least GNUTLS 3.1.10. The configuration was right all the time :)